# Loading local files via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Spent 3 hours reading reference, but still no effect, so asking here.

OS:      Windows 7 (is it relevant?)
 Browser: Opera 11.51
 jQuery:  1.6.2

---

Two files on a local machine, **main.html** and **menu.html** in the same folder.

main.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        // append contents
        $('#menu').load('menu.html');
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td id="menu"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

menu.html:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
  menu tree
  </body>
</html>
```

As I guess, when I open main.html, there should be one table with one cell containing "menu tree" string. And it works, for example, in IE. But Opera doesn't show any result.

I debugged the stuff with optional callback for load(), it shows that result status for load() is "error".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you running under a web server (`http://`) or a folder (`file://`)?

Comment: I'm running within local folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Opera you must set the flag Allow File XMLHttpRequest (opera:cofig - User Prefs).

In Google Chrome you must use option parameter --allow-file-access-from-files for run browser, for example: "C:\Documents and Settings\User\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files

Comment: Yes, this helped, but one more question. This structure (meaning interface HTML file and many other cross-referenced files which are uploaded to the interface) is intended to be deployed on CD-disk and delivered to end-users. Of course, it is not an option to ask every end-user to turn browser flags on and off. Is there a general solution for the problem?

Comment: If it's on cd, then it's static - why are you dynamically loading the menu? Just add the html without using js.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to get rid of the `<body>`, `<head>` and `<html>` tags in the Menu.html.

The way you're doing it now is invalid HTML because there is only one `<body>`, `<head>`, and `<html>` tag allowed in a document.

Change Menu.Html to

```
<p>
    Menu
</p>
```

Try that!

Comment: Did this, but still no effect.

Comment: Make sure you are on a server too. Like not on localhost, that could be your problem.